# Java Class Dynamically with Constructor parameter

Tags: java, class, dynamic, instantiation

I have to create a class dynamically but I want to use class constructor passing parameter.

Currently my code looks like

```
Class<HsaInterface> _tempClass = (Class<HsaInterface>) Class.forName(hsaClass);
        _tempClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
        HsaInterface hsaAdapter = _tempClass.newInstance();
        hsaAdapter.executeRequestTxn(txnData);
```

How can I call the constructor with the parameter ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You got close, `getDeclaredConstructor()` returns a `Constructor` object you're supposed to be using. Also, you need to pass a `String` object to the `newInstance()` method of that `Constructor`.

```
Class<HsaInterface> _tempClass = (Class<HsaInterface>) Class.forName(hsaClass);
Constructor<HsaInterface> ctor = _tempClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
HsaInterface hsaAdapter = ctor.newInstance(aString);
hsaAdapter.executeRequestTxn(txnData);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Class<HsaInterface> _tempClass = (Class<HsaInterface>) Class.forName(hsaClass);

// Gets the constructor instance and turns on the accessible flag
Constructor ctor = _tempClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
ctor.setAccessible(true);

// Appends constructor parameters
HsaInterface hsaAdapter = ctor.newInstance("parameter");

hsaAdapter.executeRequestTxn(txnData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Constructor constructor = _tempClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
Object obj = constructor.newInstance("some string");
```